# "Поймать" клик по кнопкам баннера adMob типа Interstitial

Tags: android, admob

Доброго времени суток, StackOverFlow!

Мне необходимо "поймать" клик по "крестику"/закрыть баннер или по кнопке отказа от установки предложенного приложения.

А также есть ли смысл делать кнопку "Просмотреть рекламу" в своем приложении ? И почему, если нет.

В приложении реализовал `AdListener`, в теле которого переопределил метод onAdClose(), но этот метод срабатывает только, если реклама закрыта "крестиком", а не пользователь отказался от установки чьего-то приложения.

Реклама от `adMob`.

Comment: `есть ли смысл ` известно только вам. Для начала, расскажите, какой именно рекламой вы пользуетесь.

Comment: @metalurgus, `adMob`. Извиняюсь, не указал в тексте, а только тег поставил.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете на `view` баннера наложить свою `view` с прозрачным `background`-ом и крестиком в нужном месте. По клику на свой крестик скрывать рекламу и делать нужные манипуляции.

**UPD**

```
 <FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/companies_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <-- Здесь вставьте что нужно--!>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right">

          <ImageView
               android:contentDescription="@string/close"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:duplicateParentState="true"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_ad_close"/>

     </FrameLayout>

 <FrameLayout/>
```

P.S. "поиграйтесь" с размерами `view` самостоятельно

Comment: Это , по-моему, запрещено в admob. Плюс к этому то, что мой прозрачный 'view' не будет давать возмможности кликать по самому баннеру.

Comment: это почему ещё не будет? будет

Comment: View будет на весь экран, то есть баннер будет перекрыт. И, чтобы до него добраться, нужно будет убрать сначала view. Опубликуйте, пожалуйста, код с баннером и кастомным view, может быть я ошибаюсь.

Comment: обновил ответ...

Comment: Так это же для обычного баннера, а не для interstitial.

Comment: так ведь не сложно же  в разметке изменить view на нужный?